# Can't continue deploying after for while via capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, amazon-linux

My environment is following the below.

| Environment | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Rails | 7.0.0 |
| Ruby | 3.0.0 |
| capistrano | 3.16.0 |
| Production environment | Amazon EC2 Linux |

After for while from deploying, I got these logs.

Then deploying stopped, not working anymore.

```
INFO [41bfeeb4] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /bin/systemctl stop puma_〇〇_production as deploy@〇〇

 DEBUG [41bfeeb4] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/src/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="3.0.0" ; /usr/bin/env sudo /bin/systemctl stop puma_〇〇_production )

 DEBUG [41bfeeb4] 

あなたはシステム管理者から通常の講習を受けたはずです。

これは通常、以下の3点に要約されます:

    #1) 他人のプライバシーを尊重すること。

    #2) タイプする前に考えること。

    #3) 大いなる力には大いなる責任が伴うこと。

 DEBUG [41bfeeb4]       [sudo] deploy password:
```

I think it's related to authorization.

I have no idea for fixing.

How can I do?

`deploy.rb`

```
set :application, '〇〇'
set :repo_url, '〇〇'


set :deploy_to, '/var/www/〇〇'

set :puma_threads, [4, 16]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :stage, :staging
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,
    "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_restart_command, 'bundle exec puma'
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_path, '/usr/local/src/rbenv'
set :rbenv_ruby, '3.0.0'
set :linked_dirs,
    fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push(
      'log',
      'tmp/pids',
      'tmp/cache',
      'tmp/sockets',
      'vendor/bundle',
      'public/system',
      'public/uploads',
    )
set :linked_files,
    fetch(:linked_files, []).push(
      'config/database.yml',
      'config/secrets.yml',
      'config/puma.rb',
      '.env',
    )

namespace :puma do
  Rake::Task[:restart].clear_actions

  desc 'Overwritten puma:restart task'
  task :restart do
    puts 'Overwriting puma:restart to ensure that puma is running. Effectively, we are just starting Puma.'
    puts 'A solution to this should be found.'
    invoke 'puma:stop'
    invoke 'puma:start'
  end

  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end
  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Make sure local git is in sync with remote.'
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts 'WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master'
        puts 'Run `git push` to sync changes.'
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting, :check_revision
  after :finishing, :compile_assets
  after :finishing, :cleanup
end

after 'deploy', 'sitemap:refresh'
```

`Capfile`

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/sitemap_generator'
require 'whenever/capistrano'

require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd
# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: Well it looks like the server is requiring you to enter a password for the deploy user. That being said the "error" message is very strange and almost comical when translated so not sure I can be of any assistance there.

Comment: yeah.. and after typing the password, there is no response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deploy user needs to be a sudo user in order to restart the puma systemctl service.

You can fix the issue by creating new file inside /etc/sudoers.d directory and add this line

```
deploy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I have a question. I understand that I should create a file inside /etc/sudoers.d directory. So what the file name should be..?

Comment: it doesn't matter, but a best practice to use the user's name

Comment: I created deploy-user in /etc/sudoers.d and add the line that you said. But still stopped invoke 'puma:stop' section.. does it need setting for deploy.rb or Capfile or something else?

Comment: this https://webdevchallenges.com/how-to-deploy-a-rails-6-application-with-capistrano helpful guide, maybe it helps you